# Show popup message once only

Tags: javascript, html, laravel

I have a popup message which is shown every time when users visit my web page. This is annoying and l want to show the pop up message only once. how to do that?

```js
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#popup").hide().fadeIn(1000);
        //close the POPUP if the button with id="close" is clicked
        $("#close").on("click", function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $("#popup").fadeOut(1000);
        });
    });
</script>
```

```html
<!-- Pop up message -->
<link href="myhome/popup.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<div class="body-popup" style="height: 100%; width: 100%; background-color: black">
    <div id="popup">
        <div id="close" class="alert alert-info alert-dismissable">
            <button type="button" class="pull-right close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
            CLOSE
            <img src="/myhome/assets/img/prom.jpg" alt="popup" class="image-pop"/>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Once they've seen it, save it in localStorage.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    const popup = $("#popup");
    popup.hide()
    if (localStorage.seenPopup) return;
    popup.fadeIn(1000);
    //close the POPUP if the button with id="close" is clicked
    $("#close").on("click", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#popup").fadeOut(1000);
        localStorage.seenPopup = 'true'; // value doesn't matter as long as it's not falsey
    });
});
```

Comment: Why am I only just finding out about 'localstorage'?  I'm now wondering if this is a much simpler thing to use than messing about with cookies.

Comment: @CertainPerformance thank you for your answer, I added your code but no changes.

Comment: @Muharrem Smakiqi Fixed, realized you want to call `hide()` no matter what.

Comment: @CertainPerformance I just want to show to any user only one time, if he click CLOSE, the pop up should not be displayed anymore for that user.

Comment: @Muharrem Smakiqi That's what the code does. (though, it would be more elegant for you to change the CSS if you can, so that the popup is not displayed by default, rather than calling `hide()` initially every time the page is loaded)

Answer (score 0):

You could write and check a cookie, like that:

```
...
const showPopup = $.cookie('noPopup');
if (!noPopup) {
   $("#popup").hide().fadeIn(1000);
   $("#close").on("click", function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#popup").fadeOut(1000);
        $.cookie('noPopup', true);
    });
}
....
```